# Facebook new app id not working while old id is working in same program

Tags: facebook

I have generated a new facebook app id and secret ,i did it properly and i got the key but when i use this key in my app it returns a message while same program is working properly with some other key; the message i receive  is: 
Error: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily reenable it, you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration it will be disabled permanently on August 1 2012.

some times the error is:
your app is not configured for facebook.

i have created another app that having same issue.

kindly tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable under `Settings\Advanced` the sections `August 2012 Breaking Changes` and `July 2012 Breaking Changes` and the should work fine.

However, you should modify your app functionality because from August it will stop working properly.