# Sharekit not sharing image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sharekit

I have an app in appstore which using sharekit to share image to facebook . But it is now showing the below error

```
Error: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily enable it, you may disable the "august 2012" platform migration. It will be disabled permanently on August 1, 2012.
```

In IOS6 or later i can use social framework, but it is not usefull in IOS 4.3 or so.
What can i do to share an image to facebook which supports 4.3 or later.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10613740/845115)

Comment: its not working from august onwards..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : For your `issue` refer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613740/1106035).Also refer [facebook-application-error-resolved](http://kelechizy.blogspot.in/2012/08/facebook-application-error-resolved.html#.ULcpi4Ukjxg).

Use [Facebook-Graph-API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) for `lesser version` than `iOS 5.0`.

Comment: Facebook-Graph-API image sharing not working, its crashing but other features working fine , any idea

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was because I was using an older version of Sharekit (Shame on Sharekit for not updating their site!)

Follow their Github instructions to get the latest version: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit